# SQL JOIN not working on same data types

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have a table containing a **DATE/TIME** field (*DateSubmitted*), a **LONG INTEGER** field (*Score*) and a **TEXT** field (*Team*).

I run the following query with no problems (*qry_REP_MonthlyReportedFigures*):

```
SELECT      MONTHNAME(MONTH(DateSubmitted)) AS sMonth,
            YEAR(DateSubmitted) AS lYear,
            COUNT(*) AS CountOfReportedErrors
FROM        tbl_QCErrorLog
WHERE       Team = 'Some Team'
GROUP BY    MONTH(DateSubmitted), YEAR(DateSubmitted)
```

I also run this query with no problems (*qry_REP_MonthReportedSeverityTotal*):

```
SELECT      MONTHNAME(MONTH(DateSubmitted)) AS sMonth,
            YEAR(DateSubmitted) AS lYear,
            SUM(Score) AS SeverityTotal
FROM        tbl_QCErrorLog
WHERE       Team = 'Some Team'
GROUP BY    MONTH(DateSubmitted), YEAR(DateSubmitted)
```

However, if I then run a third query based on these two queries it doesn't join them properly and I get **#Error** in *ST.sMonth* and blanks/nulls in *ST.lYear* and *SeverityTotal*

```
SELECT      RF.sMonth, 
            RF.lYear, 
            RF.CountOfReportedErrors,
            ST.sMonth,
            ST.lYear,
            ST.SeverityTotal
FROM        qry_REP_MonthlyReportedFigures RF LEFT JOIN qry_REP_MonthReportedSeverityTotal ST
            ON RF.lYear = ST.lYear AND RF.sMonth = ST.sMonth
```

I'd expect there to be no problems joining as all data types are the same - they're from the same source after all.

If I join on just the month it works, but that will cause problems in a years time when I have figures from the same month in different years.  If I join on just the year I get the **#Error** again.

Now, if I update the *qry_REP_MonthReportedSeverityTotal* SQL to cast the month name to a string and the year to a long integer everything works:

```
SELECT      CSTR(MONTHNAME(MONTH(DateSubmitted))) AS sMonth,
            CLNG(YEAR(DateSubmitted)) AS lYear,
            SUM(Score) AS SeverityTotal
FROM        tbl_QCErrorLog
WHERE       Team = 'Some Team'
GROUP BY    MONTH(DateSubmitted), YEAR(DateSubmitted)
```

So, although I've resolved the problem, does anyone have any idea why the original query didn't work?

**EDIT:**  Really confused now - I leave the office for 5 minutes, come back and now it doesn't work unless I cast both the queries to string and long integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why `qry_REP_MonthlyReportedFigures` get data from `tbl_QCErrorLog` but `qry_REP_MonthReportedSeverityTotal` get data from `tbl_QC_ErrorLog`?

This query should give you expected result without `JOIN`:

```
SELECT      MONTHNAME(MONTH(DateSubmitted)) AS sMonth,
            YEAR(DateSubmitted) AS lYear,
            COUNT(*) AS CountOfReportedErrors
            SUM(Score) AS SeverityTotal
FROM        tbl_QCErrorLog
WHERE       Team = 'Some Team'
GROUP BY    MONTH(DateSubmitted), YEAR(DateSubmitted)
```

Comment: Good spot - both meant to be `tbl_QCErrorLog`.  It's because I use Notepad++ to write the SQL and copy paste to Access - that way I can keep the SQL in a readable format without Access adding a hundred brackets and alias's and all the other rubbish it likes to do.

Comment: Yep, that query works.  Think I was looking into the query too much - the first two queries answered separate questions on my final report so I took those values without thinking.  I guess that's what happens when you're working through an existing Powerpoint presentation (with figures taken from Excel) and reproducing the figures in Access - I'm just going page by page rather than compiling everything I need before touching the keyboard.

Comment: Not sure whether to mark this as the answer though - it does give a better solution to the query, but doesn't answer why the two queries wouldn't join when it appears they should.